# phpmyadmin doesn't work what is the problem

Tags: phpmyadmin, laragon

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of PhpMyAdmin\Response::isAjax() must be of the type boolean, null returned in C:\laragon\etc\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php:238 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\etc\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(504): PhpMyAdmin\Response->isAjax() #1 [internal function]: PhpMyAdmin\Response->response() #2 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\etc\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php on line 238

Answer (score 0):

Check if the php extension 'opcache' is not enabled; It was my case.

Comment: I have exact same problem installing php extension opcache does not help. This may be related with freebsd version of php. I have php8.1 and I made this: sudo pkg install php81-opcache-8.1.1. Command `php -m` show this: Core
date
hash
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
pcre
Reflection
session
SPL
standard
xml. 
Zend modules are empty.

Comment: I succesfully configured opcache: `php -m` has [Zend Modules] Zend OPcache. But I am still getting same error like described by questioner.

Comment: SOLVED. Problem was missing `mbstring` php module.